# C++ Qt - When a slot is called, is the function called a new thread?

Tags: multithreading, qt, slot

I would like to know if the function `do_something()` is treated as a new thread, when I click on `my_button`.

```
connect(my_button, SIGNAL(clicked), this, SLOT(do_something));
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The typical signal/slot behavior is determined based on the [connection type](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qt.html#ConnectionType-enum). When unspecified, it defaults to `Qt::AutoConnection` and will use the receiver's thread if a direct connection can't be made.

From the docs:

> The slot is invoked when control returns to the event loop of the receiver's thread. The slot is executed in the receiver's thread.

You can change the [connection type](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qt.html#ConnectionType-enum) at connect time to alter the behavior:

```
connect(my_button, SIGNAL(clicked), this, SLOT(do_something),
    Qt::QueuedConnection); // always queue
```

Since you're talking about a button that's emitting the signal, the default connection type of `Qt::AutoConnection` implies that a direct connection is made and that the `do_something` slot will be executed immediately as if it had been called directly at the point the button was clicked.

Comment: I had no idea Qt managed the type of connection. I am reading the documentation, yet something isn't clear: 

"(default) If the signal is emitted from a different thread than the receiving object."

Could you define "from a different thread"? More specifically, I know what and how multi-threading works. I don't know how Qt manages its things, and I am guessing there is a hidden system of threads.

Comment: @Bibi541: No hidden threads, but if you create your own QThread's, they can have their own event loops, and QObjects assigned/created to those threads will have autoconnection slots called on their thread, not the emitting object's thread (usually the main/ui loop for QButtons and the like...)

Comment: Some notes: A direction connection is just a function call with some connection lookup in between and completely synchronous. A queued connection (without moving objects into different threads consciously) schedules a call in the event loop, but that's still single-threaded.

Comment: All in all, a slot is never called in a new thread. Even if the thread of the receiver is different from the thread of the sender, this can only be because *you* yourself created that thread and created the receiving object in that thread. Qt doesn't create any new threads under the hood.